# How to calculate a Modulo?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I really can't get my head around this "modulo" thing.

Can someone show me a general step-by-step procedure on how I would be able to find out the 5 modulo 10, or 10 modulo 5.

Also, what does this mean: 1/17 = 113 modulo 120 ?

Because when I calculate(using a calculator) 113 modulo 120, the result is 113. But what is the 1/17 standing for then?

THANK YOU!

Comment: Modulo means,remainder after doing division so if you say 10 modulo 5 compute 10/5 and the remainder is what comes out of modulo

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{17}\equiv113\pmod{120}$ means that (the class of) $17$ is invertible in the ring $\mathbb Z/120\mathbb Z$ (classes modulo $120$). But even more, that $113$ is the (class) inverse of $17$. In fact, now not in classes modulo $120$ but in integers
$$17\cdot 113=1921=16\cdot120+1$$ which means that, in classes modulo $120$, you have $$17\cdot113=0+1=1$$

Comment: A simple visualization; for modulo 5 picture a gear with 5 teeth.  Because of the wrap around your counting is wrapped to the same tooth.   The tooth number is the modulo.

Answer (score 17):

When you see "modulo", especially if you are using a calculator, think of it as the remainder term when you do division.

Examples:

The result of `10 modulo 5` *is* `0` because the remainder of `10 / 5` *is* `0`.

The result of `7 modulo 5` *is* `2` because the remainder of `7 / 5` *is* `2`.

The reason your calculator says `113 modulo 120 = 113` is because *113 < 120*, so it isn't doing any division.

More generally, the idea is that two numbers are *congruent* if they are the same modulo a given number (or modulus)

For example, as above, $7 \equiv 2 \mod 5$ where $5$ is our modulus.

Another issue is that of inverses, which is where the confusion of $1/17$ comes in.

We say that $a$ and $b$ are inverses modulo $n$, if $ab \equiv 1 \mod n$, and we might write $b = a^{-1}$.

For example $17\cdot 113 = 1921 = 120\cdot 16 +1 \equiv 1 \mod 120$, 
so $17^{-1} = 113$ modulo $120$.

Comment: I also have this question so can you say if 231mod 1000=231mod 125 and 231 mod 8 or something like that. Please

Comment: Well, to compute it, you need to do long division with the two numbers and compute the remainder. For example,

Comment: $231 = 125 + 106$, so that $231 \mod 125 = 106$.

Answer (score 6):

There are ways to calculate it, modulo is remainder counting basically.
$$7 = 2 \mod 5$$
because $7=5*1+2$
$$12 = 2 \mod 5$$
because $12=5*2+2$
and so on, so if you want to calculate for example $73 = a \mod 7$ you can do this, that is want to get $a$, take 73 and continue subtracting 7 until you no longer can. $73-7=66$, $66-7=59$ etc until we get $10-7=3$ which gives us that $a=3$ in it's simplest form (any of the results along the way can technically be a).

As for what $1/17=113 \mod 120$ the question is simply what times 17 gives remainder 1 when divided by 120?
$113\cdot 17 = 1921 = 120\cdot 16+1$

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Modulo is counting when knowing only a limited amount of numbers. E.g. modulo three, instead of counting

$$0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,...$$

you count

$$
\underset{\color{lightgray}0}0,
\underset{\color{lightgray}1}1,
\underset{\color{lightgray}2}2,\;\;
\underset{\color{lightgray}3}0,
\underset{\color{lightgray}4}1,
\underset{\color{lightgray}5}2,\;\;
\underset{\color{lightgray}6}0,
\underset{\color{lightgray}7}1,
\underset{\color{lightgray}8}2,\;\;
\underset{\color{lightgray}9}0,
\underset{\color{lightgray}{10}}1,
\underset{\color{lightgray}{11}}2,...$$

As you can see, you will end up at zero whenever the actual number is *divisible by three*. So finding the nearest multiples of three will help you to find its value moldulo three.

**Example**. $362$ is close to $360=3\times 120$. Since it is two larger than $360$, it is equivalent to $2$ modulo three. As explained in the other answers you could have found this using division with rest.

The "$1/17$ modulo $120$" is just a short form of the question "what number $x\in\{1,...,119\}$ do I have to multiply by $17$ so that the result $17x$ is equivalent to $1$ modulo $120$?". In this case, it is $113$.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain what about my answer dissatisfied them?

Answer (score 2):

The "mod" operator in computer languages is simply the remainder. For example,

```
17 mod 3 = 2
```

because

```
17 / 3 = 5 rem 2
```

which in turn means

```
17 = 3 * 5 + 2
```

Comment: Also sometimes mod is shown as the symbol %

Answer (score 1):

A better understanding/formula of modulo is:

```
X / Y = Z (int) * Y = A | X - A = B | X %% Y = B
```

Three calculations to be made

```
16 %% 6 = 4 ???
```

Explanation:

```
X = 16, Y = 6
16/6=2.67
```

Remove .67 since its integer/floor division removing decimals so it's 2.

```
2 * 6 = 12
16 - 12 = 4
```

Modulo = 4
Or even better explanations in bottom of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664301/how-does-modulus-divison-work

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to understand this "modulo" operation. Consider the positive integers $7,12,17,22,27,32,...$ All these integers leave $5$ as the remainder when divided by $5$. In other words, if we subtract $2$ from each integer, the resulting set is a set multiples of $5$. We can travel on the other direction also. The integers $2,-3,-8,...$ also have that property, i.e., if we subtract $2$ from each integer, the resulting set is a set of multiples of $5$. Thus the set $\{...-8,-3,2,7,12,17,22,...\}$ will become a set of multiples of $5$ if we subtract $2$ from each. We call this set as $2$ modulo $5$. So, whenever we say $2$ modulo $5$, we mean a number which leaves $2$ as the remainder when divided by $5$. If $x \equiv 2 \pmod 5$, then $x -2$ is a multiple of $5$.