# What's the remainder when this huge number is divided by 45?

Tags: number-theory

One of my friends recently gave a mock test of a math exam in which he was asked this horrific question. He asked the same to me and I was totally blank on looking at it. So, it will be a huge help if any of you can solve this.
Here is the question:

A 79 digit long number is made by writing the natural numbers from 1 to 44 in order like  1234567891011121314.....424344. What is the remainder when this number is divided by 45?

Thanks in advance!
Enjoy Solving!

Comment: Well, clearly your number is $4\pmod 5$, so you just need to compute it $\pmod 9$.  That you can do by summing the digits.  Or, more easily, by arguing that you just need to compute $\sum_{n=1}^{44} n \pmod 9$

Comment: I am sorry @lulu but I didn't get what you're trying to say?

Comment: @UditJethva: look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Comment: Where are you confused?  If you know the remainder modulo $5,9$ you can use the Chinese remainder theorem to compute it $\pmod {45}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3152587/largest-multiple-of-7-lower-than-some-78-digit-number/3152669#3152669  might help a bit, if you know enough math. phi(45)=32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be your number, let $y$ be its remainder when divided by 45.

Since $x$ and $y$ differ by a multiple of $45$, and each multiple of $45$ is also a multiple of $5$ and a multiple of $9$, $x$ and $y$ have the same remainders when divided by $5$, and also when divided by $9$.

So what you need to do is find the remainders of $x$ when divided by $5$ and by $9$, and then find the number $y$ between $0$ and $44$ that has the same remainders.

Comment: I can find out the remainder when it's divided by 5 but how am i going to find it when it's divided by 9? Please help.

Comment: @UditJethva: do you know divisibility by $9$ rule? Find the sum of digits and divide it by 9, the remainder will be the same when you divide the original number

Comment: Yes I do know that but the problem is that how am I going to find the sum of the digits?

Comment: By adding them up. There's only 79 of them, it isn't that hard. You can rearrange them to make it go faster (10 twos sum to 20, for example, and the digits 1 to 9 sum to 45).

Comment: @UditJethva: Modulo $9$, the sum of the digits in the long number is also the sum of the digits in the sum $1+2+3+\dots+44$.  There's a formula for that.

Comment: Sorry to say @awkward, but that is incorrect as for example adding numbers like 44 would mean that 40 + 4 is added instead of 4 + 4

Comment: Yes, it's not the same sum, but it still has the same remainder when divided by 9, and that's all you need anyway.

Comment: @UditJethva If you don't know the formula you can use [Gauss's trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/44964/242) as in my answer. This exploitation of reflection symmetry is [widely applicable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+symmetry+involution)

Comment: @UditJethva I said the results are the same *modulo 9*.  In your example, note that $4+4$ and $44$ both are $8$, modulo $9$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: I'd use the Chinese remainder theorem, which says that the mapping
$${\Bbb Z}_{45} \rightarrow {\Bbb Z}_5\times {\Bbb Z}_9: x\mapsto (x\mod 5, x\mod 9)$$
is a ring isomorphism.

Thus you can separately divide the large number by 5 and by 9. These remainders can then be combined to obtained the remainder modulo 45.

Modulo 5 the situation is simple, just look at the last digit of the number.

Modulo 9, observe that $10 \equiv 1 \mod 9$ and so $10^n\equiv 1 \mod 9$ for each $n\geq 1$. So modulo 9 you just look for the ''Quersumme'' (cross sum).

So you have to find a number $x$ between 0 and 44  such that $x$ is congruent 4 modulo 5 and congruent $Q$ modulo 9, where $Q$ is the cross sum of your number.

This number is congruent 4 mod 5 and so is one of the following: 4, 9, 14, 19, 24, 29, 34, 39, 44.

Comment: With all due respect to the OP, I doubt that bringing ring isomorphisms into the picture will help them to solve their problem.

Comment: I would agree: answers shouldn't be more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @TonyK: It solves the problem. Please check.

Comment: Reading the OP's question, I would guess that Udit can't tell a ring isomorphism from a hole in the ground. So it's not much of a hint, is it?

Comment: @TonyK I've now described the solution procedure which should be doable by somebody who has no access to ring theory. The down voting is unjustified.

Comment: Downvoting is justified by "This answer is not useful". That is a stronger condition than "This answer is not useful for the OP". If the answer is okay than at least others might have profit.

Comment: Come on you serious mathematicians, think about my solution. Its the easiest one can think of. And this holds for every large number the OP can present.

Comment: Upvoted. What's the matter with the downvoters? Even if it is too difficult for the OP, it can be useful for someone else!

Answer (score 2):

$\color{#c00}{n \equiv 4}\pmod{5}$ by its unit digit $= 4$, and $\,n\equiv 0\pmod{9}\,$ by [casting out nines](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16015/242) as below

$$\begin{align} 1 &+\ \  2 + \cdots + 22\\ +\ 44 &+ 43 + \cdots +23\\ \hline 45 &+ 45 + \cdots +45\end{align}\qquad\qquad $$

Thus $\ n\bmod 45 = 9 (\color{#c00}n/9  \bmod 5) = 9(\color{#c00}4/4\bmod 5) = 9\,$ by the [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242).