# Can we build a generic linear algebraic machinery to calculate divisibility on decimal numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

A couple well known rules for divisibility exist, let us start with the smaller one:

Divisibility by 3: A number is divisible by 3 if and only if it's digit sum is divisible by 3.

Divisibility by 5: A number is divisible by 5 if and only if it's last digit is either 0 or 5.

It seems what we need so far is some framework (at least be) able to

1. pick out single digits and
2. to calculate sums
3. iterate on all resulting numbers $\mathbb Z \backslash \{0,1,\cdots,9\}$
4. compare to a base case (set of integers $\subset \{0,1,\cdots,9\}$)

Multiplying with a vector $\bf v$ can achieve this. Summing the elements of a vector corresponds to scalar product with vector full of ones. Picking out last element corresponds to scalar product with vector $[0,\cdots,0,1]^T$.

Now to the tricky part. Can we mathematically prove that such a scalar product vector $v$ and set of end-up numbers $\mathcal S$ must exist for *any* divisor $ d\in \mathbb Z$?

**Own work**

- Case $d=5, {\bf v}=[0,1]^T, \mathcal S = \{0,5\}$, for the subset $\{0,1,\cdots,99\}$
- Case $d=7, {\bf v}=[3,1]^T, \mathcal S = \{7\}$, for the subset $\{0,1,\cdots,99\}$
- Case $d=11, {\bf v}=[1,-1]^T, \mathcal S = \{0\}$, for the subset $\{0,1,\cdots,99\}$

Comment: I mean, we can take the sequence $10^k$ mod $d$, as we sometimes do. But I would assume that expecting the base cases to be in $\{0,\cdots, 9\}$ is too much to ask for large $d$.

Comment: Also, I don't understand what you do with $7$ exactly. Do you mean summing the unit digit to three times the integer quotient of $n$ by $10$?

Comment: for the number 21 we do scalar product $[3,1][2,1]^T = 3\cdot 2+1 \cdot 1 = 7 $ which is in our set so we have verified divisibility. If it was outside of the set it would have been disqualified.

Comment: Yeah. but what do you do with $946587$?

Comment: @Gae.S. : Then we need to make larger vector space and find longer vectors to do scalar products with. I think you are on to something with this sequence.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3152587/largest-multiple-of-7-lower-than-some-78-digit-number/3152669#3152669

Comment: @Gae raise it to a power, sufficient so it's length exceeds the order of 10 mod the prime.  Base convert it to base p ?  Convert it to a lower base, so it's length exceeds the order/cycle length in that base. Apply polynomial remainder theorem to change it to the same representation in a different base where you can tell figuring what changes). probably more.

Comment: you actually prompted me to think about the linked problem more, thank you.