# The chunking aspect of repunit prime factors

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization, repunit-numbers

While others have already mentioned the divisibility of decimal repunits,

$$m := \frac{{10}^n - 1}{9}.$$

```
 1  1
 2  11                                11
 3  111                               3 37
 4  1111                              11 101

 5  11111                             41 271
 6  111111                            3 7 11 13 37
 7  1111111                           239 4649
 8  11111111                          11 73 101 137

 9  111111111                         3^2 37 333667
10  1111111111                        11 41 271 9091
11  11111111111                       21649 513239
12  111111111111                      3 7 11 13 37 101 9901

13  1111111111111                     53 79 265371653
14  11111111111111                    11 239 4649 909091
15  111111111111111                   3 31 37 41 271 2906161
16  1111111111111111                  11 17 73 101 137 5882353

17  11111111111111111                 2071723 5363222357
18  111111111111111111                3^2 7 11 13 19 37 52579 333667
19  1111111111111111111               1111111111111111111
20  11111111111111111111              11 41 101 271 3541 9091 27961

21  111111111111111111111             3 37 43 239 1933 4649 10838689
22  1111111111111111111111            11^2 23 4093 8779 21649 513239
23  11111111111111111111111           11111111111111111111111
24  111111111111111111111111          3 7 11 13 37 73 101 137 9901 99990001

25  1111111111111111111111111         41 271 21401 25601 182521213001
26  11111111111111111111111111        11 53 79 859 265371653 1058313049
27  111111111111111111111111111       3^3 37 757 333667 440334654777631
28  1111111111111111111111111111      11 29 101 239 281 4649 909091 121499449

29  11111111111111111111111111111     3191 16763 43037 62003 77843839397
30  111111111111111111111111111111    3 7 11 13 31 37 41 211 241 271 2161 9091 2906161
31  1111111111111111111111111111111   2791 6943319 57336415063790604359
```

I think a practical use of this divisibility is frequently overlooked :

> - For really gigantic inputs, one may literally stack wide band of digits on top of each others, and sum up the stacks, before performing any sort of modular arithmetic.

e.g.    `12 111111111111 : 3 7 11 13 37 101 9901`

One can stack every 12-digits directly on top of each other if one wants to calculate any of the combination of all these prime factors, which would massively speed up primality checking for small factors

for instance, to perform a quick test on

```
  7407457283755447477426709403332725993034294823928945951559129
  6149310316146786637645823164508144688817069018866259431952169
```

---

```
                             74 
 + 074572837554 =   74572837628 
 + 474774267094 =  549347104722 
 + 033327259930 =  582674364652 

 + 342948239289 =  925622603941 
 + 459515591296 = 1385138195237 
 + 149310316146 = 1534448511383 

 + 786637645823 = 2321086157206 
 + 164508144688 = 2485594301894 
 + 817069018866 = 3302663320760 
 + 259431952169 = 3562095272929
 ------------------------------
              3,562,095,272,929
```

Let's test them all except `9901` :

```
3 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 37 * 101 := 11,222,211
```

---

```
 ( 3562095272929 % 11222211 ) %   3 := ( 8390575 %   3 ) :=    1 | 3562095272929 %   3 ==   1 
 ( 3562095272929 % 11222211 ) %   7 := ( 8390575 %   7 ) :=    4 | 3562095272929 %   7 ==   4 
 ( 3562095272929 % 11222211 ) %  11 := ( 8390575 %  11 ) :=    6 | 3562095272929 %  11 ==   6 
 ( 3562095272929 % 11222211 ) %  13 := ( 8390575 %  13 ) :=   11 | 3562095272929 %  13 ==  11 
 ( 3562095272929 % 11222211 ) %  37 := ( 8390575 %  37 ) :=   11 | 3562095272929 %  37 ==  11 
 ( 3562095272929 % 11222211 ) % 101 := ( 8390575 % 101 ) :=    0 | 3562095272929 % 101 ==   0
```

Which indeed, has correctly identified `101` as a factor, since the original value was generated via

```
    7407457283755447477426709403332725993034294823928945951559129
    6149310316146786637645823164508144688817069018866259431952169: 101^13 23456789^13
```

So instead of requiring a big-integer library, even before we perform any sort of modular arithmetic on it, this chunking approach already pre-reduced the problem to something that can fit within 64-bit data types.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So like: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3152669/903195 but also not phrased as a question.

Comment: Also chunking is still modulo just using size carmichael totient ...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee : It's just an extrapolation of an existing idea so one wouldn't have to re-perform the same chunking for other primes that share common properties when performing upfront pre-filtering of small primes during primality check. Another point I didn't mention above is using a rapid `mod 11` test for palindromes, which would be a huge time saver when the left and right halves don't even match.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee : or for something like `mod 3`, even chunking decimal digits, no matter how wide, is waaaay too slow.

Comment: Mod 3 is reducible to difference in number of {2,5,8} and {1,4,7} if a multiple of 3, then it's divisible.

Comment: And mod 11 is just the subtraction of 2 values one for even placed digits, the other from odd placed digits

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee : which is waaaaay too slow of a chunking method for a computer if you try feeding it a numeric string representing 20 mn decimal digits. Chunk first, THEN do the odd/even thing, cuz chunking is just a mindless summation exercise. As for `mod 3`, after fudging around a bit, I realized any attempts to even perform any sort of base conversion is a waste of time, and that, ironically, regular expressions are actually the fastest way.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee : this is my own mod3 module : `function mod3(_) {
 return (sub("^0[Xx]", "", _)) < (substr(_, 76, 1) == "") ? (length(_) <= +15 ? _ : substr(_, 1, 15) + substr(_, 16, 15) + substr(_, 31, 15) + substr(_, 46, 15) + substr(_, 61)) % 3 : 0 * (gsub("[ -0369CFILORUXcfx_\n]+", "", _)) + (length(_) * 2 + gsub("[258BEHKNQTWZbe]+", "", _) * 0 - length(_)) % 3
}`: decimals up to 75-digits have shortcut logic upfront, otherwise, inputs of ANY base within [4,7,10,13,16,19,22,25,28,31,34]…..

Comment: ….  directly uses regular expressions to compute the mod3 without ever wasting a moment converting any of them into either decimal or binary, which makes this function extremely scalable of inputs even up to a billion digits without breaking a sweat. When inputs go beyond a couple million digits, the speed gap against `gmp` rapidly widens, as `gmp` spends all its time performing base pre-conversion of inputs, so its performance is no longer `O(n)` to base-10, but regular expressions are.

Comment: that function easily could've been extended to be inclusive of bases up to 62, with nearly zero penalty for other bases, but I stopped at 34 because of the hideous property of the english alphabet failing to wrap-around, mod 3, so I opted to handle case-insensitive hex instead. but in exchange, the function doesn't even require the user to specify which input base it was in, as long as it's one in the list above. The only quirk with this function in present form is that negative inputs would have their modulos inverted